# How to view any folder as if it was desktop

Tags: folders, desktop

There's a folder called "Desktop" in the home directory. By default, when there are no windows on the screen, the contents of "Desktop" are shown over the background. I'm wondering if there's a way to make another folder show up over the background instead, so that I could (for example) have the contents of "Documents" or something like that appear behind my windows.

Right now I can do it by moving the contents of another folder into the "Desktop" folder and moving them back when I'm done, but I feel like there much be an easier way to do this, especially since copying takes a long time with some larger files.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653159/7886229):

> **Backup your old default Desktop folder**
>
> If you have files in your existing Desktop folder, don’t worry. We’re
>   going to back up your existing folder so you can copy your old Desktop
>   files to your new DropBox Desktop folder afterwards.
>
> Simply open a terminal and enter the following command.
>
> ```
> sudo mv desktop desktop.bak
> ```
>
> **Create a symbolic link to your new DropBox Desktop folder**
>
> The long and short is that we’re telling OSX to create a link to the
>   Desktop folder in your DropBox, but to treat the link as if it were
>   the default Desktop folder itself. In this way, when you save things
>   to your Mac Desktop, they’ll appear on your Desktop as before, but
>   actually be stored in your new DropBox folder. Here’s how to do it…
>
> ```
> ln -s /Users/your-user-name/Dropbox/Desktop/ ./Desktop
> ```
>
> This worked perfectly for me.
>
> Credit goes to
>   https://ifyouwillit.com/life/auto-sync-your-mac-desktop-folder-with-dropbox/

**Please upvote both question and answer on linked Q&A**

Comment: This won’t work if you use iCloud storage for your Desktop and documents

Comment: @Tim It should be able to be adapted. Something like `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/XXXXXXXXX\~com\~apple\~Desktop`

Comment: I don’t know how iCloud handles symbolic links, and it could mean the contents of the Documents folder be synced twice.

Comment: @Tim I don't sync mine. Could you test?

Comment: That's good, thanks. I'm looking to do this regularly, and I noticed that if you do this multiple times, you have to rename the directory that you're symlinking to in order to have the displayed directory update. So, each time I do this I have to go 'rm Desktop; sudo mv folderthatwaslinked newnameforlinkedfolder; ln -s newfolderIwanttolink Desktop'. Is there a way to set it up so that the directory that's being displayed updates quickly, without having to rename it?

Comment: @GabrielBrookman Do you mean remove the symlink? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932906/how-do-i-remove-a-symlink

Comment: If you just remove the symlink, which directory is displayed in the background is not immediately updated, you have to rename the old directory that was displayed in order for anything to happen. I'm looking for a way to not have to do this.

Comment: @GabrielBrookman I see. Gimme a bit I'll write a script.

Comment: @JBis if you force quit and relaunch finder after reassigning the symlink, it also works out. Thanks.